# Update mysql database

Tags: mysql

How would I go about updating MySQL database X, table Y and column Z with "abc". How would I be able to do this without having to do so interactively from the mysql> prompt? I want to do this with one simple command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a password for your user to prevent use in on scripts:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=user --password # you will be asked for the password.
```

Then, from a script or terminal, use something like this:

```
mysql --login-path=local --database=X -e "update Y set column Z='abc';"
```

Or, you can use the insecure way:

```
mysql --user=user --password=pass --host=localhost --database=X -e "update Y set column Z='abc';"
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do it with mysql -u user -pPASSWORD Query??

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting the following error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column userid='abc'' at line 1

Comment: That's an error in your SQL syntax. Maybe you wrote incorrectly the field name or something like that. Can't answer with such information.